# How to disable automated SMS responses in Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

In March I opened a website that provides people with temporary numbers to be used to receive SMS verifications etc.

I've just logged in to the account and realised that I've received a ton of charges for outbound SMS.

They appear to be a default automated response whenever any of my numbers receives a SMS.

I didn't enable this (seems as though it's some sort of money making thing on their side). How do I disable it?

Comment: Send a SMS to one of your numbers. What is the message you get back?

Comment: Or you can check in the outbound logs to see what it says.

Answer (score 11):

Go to your project, open https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming and select the number. In `Messaging` in `A MESSAGE COMES IN` select `TwiML` and click `Plus` button. Give it some name and paste

`<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<Response></Response>`

there. Save

Answer (score 10):

Twilio evangelist here.

When you buy a Twilio phone number it comes configured with a default Message Request URL that uses the [TwiML `<Sms>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms) verb to send a reply back to any incoming text message.

```
<Response>
    <Sms>Thanks for the message. Configure your number's SMS URL to change this message.Reply HELP for help.Reply STOP to unsubscribe.Msg&Data rates may apply.</Sms>
</Response>
```

If you want to prevent those replies you can change this default behavior by providing your own Message Request URL or by using our integrated TwiMLBin feature and returning an empty TwiML response to Twilio:

```
<Response />
```

Here is an article from our FAQ that has more info:

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-can-i-receive-sms-messages-without-responding

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can I just remove that URL so the box is blank?

Comment: That will stop Twilio from both receiving and replying to messages for that phone number.

Comment: this is crazy. such a simple thing gives such a headache. I still can't disable goddamn replies. Just do a ducking checkbox there already

Answer (score 5):

### (2021 Update)

Few things were updated in Twilio / mainly their Admin Dashboard GUI but I'll try to simplify it for anyone reading this still. Trust me when I say I completely understand the frustration of the lack of simplicity when it comes to how they operate. The phrase "Work Smarter, Not Harder" doesn't exist in that company (lol):

- Log into your Admin Dashboard Account: https://www.twilio.com/login
- Go to your Active Phone Numbers: https://console.twilio.com/?frameUrl=/console/phone-numbers/

  - If that URL changes, add **Active Phone Numbers** to your **Develop** dashboard first VIA

  **Develop Tab** -> **Explore Products** -> CTRL + F "**Phone
  Numbers**" -> Click the **Pin Button**

  [image: Add Active Numbers to Admin Dashboard]

  - Then access your **Active Phone Numbers** VIA

  **Develop Tab** -> **Phone Numbers** -> **Manage** -> **Active Numbers** -> Click  **Active (###) ###-####**
  [image: Link to Phone Number]

  Scroll down to **Messaging** -> Select **Webhooks, TwiML Bins, Functions, Studio, or Proxy** is selected for **Configure With Other Handlers** -> Select **Function** for **When a Message Comes In** -> Select **Default** for Service -> then leave the **Function Path** empty.
  [image: Messaging Configuration Settings]